# Minor error in tag definition system?

Tags: bug, tags

I have a [Fairphone](http://www.fairphone.com/) (Yes, the 'seriously cool smartphone' ;-)) and tried to put a tag 'FairPhone' below my first post. The error I got was that I cannot define new tags below 300 rep.

However I can define it as a *favorite* tag (top right; did that some weeks ago).

Is this a small error in the system (i.e. not checking the rep at that location)?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the tag to your favourites doesn't actually create the tag, so it doesn't matter whether you have enough reputation or not. It just adds that tag name to a list in your profile. If a tag is subsequently created with that name, the tag will be in your favourites; until then, it has no effect.

If there's an error here, it's only that the behaviour is a little confusing.

BTW, there's not much point adding a new tag if there's only one question it relates to. Tags with one or zero questions are automatically removed after some time.

We also wouldn't normally add a device tag to [this particular question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/64277/12442), because it doesn't appear to be specific to this model: the same problem could just as easily arise with a different device.